# unable to get tredns in twitteR argument "woeid" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I would like to get trends, using packages"twitteR". When I type searchTwitter(""0, it works. However, when I type getTrends(period=""), it shows: Error in getTrends(period = "weekly") : 
  argument "woeid" is missing, with no default 
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Look at the help `?searchTwitter` where is says _woeid: A numerical identification code describing a location, a Yahoo! Where On Earth ID_. Then, I'd try here: https://www.google.com/search?q=Yahoo!+Where+On+Earth+ID

Answer (score 0):

The woeid specifies the the location in order to pull the trends for a given place/country. To get the global Trends you can use `getTrends(1)`
To find a desired woeid you can use the function:

```
a_trends = availableTrendLocations()
head(a_trends)
```

Or:

```
 closeTrends = closestTrendLocations(your_lon, your_lat)
 head(closeTrends)
```